# Postgres "Connection timed out" when connecting from debian and ubuntu clients, but fine from Windows

Tags: postgresql, docker, debian, digital-ocean, psql

**Update**:

This seems to be related to just how Docker changes the iptables and leaves its settings even after disabling its iptables rule setting capabilities. Issue can be resolved by modifying `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and setting `{ "iptables": true }`

I just did a fresh install of Debian 11. Installed postgres without docker, and was able to connect to my server. I just installed docker and tried to connect from a postgres container and was not able to reach server. This issue seems to be related to firewalling around docker.

I am running postgres 13.4 on a debian server through docker, hosted on DigitalOcean. I've setup a very open config just to see if I can connect to my server from various clients that are not local. Here is how I've configured my `pg_hba.conf` file:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
#host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

`postgresql.conf`:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'
```

My way to connect from client side is to use a postgres docker container so that I can use the `psql` command without installing postgres on that client. I've tried 3 different client machines.

Windows 10 from home network works fine:

```
root@7eb2296a9cf6:/# psql -h 111.222.143.193 -p 5432 -U postgres
Password for user postgres:
```

Debian 10 from home network fails:

```
root@38161cc233c1:/# psql -h 111.222.143.193 -p 5432 -U postgres
psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on host "111.222.143.193" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Ubuntu 20.04 from Linode network fails:

```
root@3706fd7cbdd4:/# psql -h 111.222.143.193 -p 5432 -U postgres
psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on host "111.222.143.193" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Here is the UFW status (I've changed the IP for privacy)

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
787/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
Anywhere                   ALLOW       93.551.148.352
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
5432                       ALLOW       Anywhere
787/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5432 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: Wanna make a bet it is a IPv4 vs IPv6 thing? Is there a firewall set up and is configured to allow traffic through to port 5432 via both v4 and v6? You might also want to change the `pg_hba.conf` to allow remote connections from v6 e.g. `::0/0`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver My clients are all configured to use IPV4 only. That said, I changed as you advised to allow for IPV6 
`host    all             all             ::0/0                 md5`

No luck

Comment: Before the connection could be screened by `pg_hba.conf` it would need to get past any firewall. I just suggested the v6 setting to cover connections coming in on that protocol.  The errors you are getting are consistent with a firewall blocking access. Verify if you have a firewall or firewalls in effect and what their settings are.

Comment: I use UFW for firewall on the Ubuntu asset. I've disabled it and tried connecting and no luck. I've also opened up ports 80, 443, and 5432 on the client side just because I was running out of ideas.

Comment: Did you checked this [Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/697187/postgresql-connection-timed-out) ?

Comment: @ChihebNexus Yes. Most posts have mentioned the same notes about the postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf. That's why I included it in my post. The windows client actually connects to the server.

Comment: So is the Ubuntu asset the Digital Ocean instance? Also, then there is the interface between the Docker container and whatever host it is running on. You need to update your question with a more detailed description of hoops the connection has to jump through to get to the Postgres server.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This seems to be related to how Docker changes the iptables and leaves its settings even after disabling its iptables rule setting capabilities. Issue can be resolved by setting `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and setting `{ "iptables": true }`

Another approach is to work with iptables directly.